# How do I show files or progress while listing directory contents using Cocoa NSDirectoryEnumerator?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm new to Cocoa/Objective-C.  I'm coding for Mac OS X 10.6 using Xcode 4 (and Garbage Collection required).

How would I make it possible for the following code (based on Apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/EnumADir.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000783-BAJFBAAH)) to update my GUI so that the GUI shows either a count of the files being listed or the filenames themselves?  I already know that I can't just create an outlet to a label and update the label's text.  Where the `NSLog` calls are made are places where I might want to update a status in the GUI.

I'm guessing that this would involve putting the task on some other process/thread?  I've done some reading on multiprocessing using NSTask, multithreading and GCD. Apart from multithreading (which I want to avoid), I do not really know which I should use. I think I could knock something together but would prefer to do it an optimal or recommended way (and implement it quickly).

My impression is that NSTask will be suitable for my simple requirements?

I will also want to give the user the option to pause or cancel the long-running task.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLIsPackageKey, NSURLLocalizedNameKey, nil]; 

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                                    enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                         includingPropertiesForKeys:keys 
                                            options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles) 
                                       errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) { 
                                           // Handle the error.
                                           // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error. 
                                     return YES; 
                                       }
                                    ]; 

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) { 
    // Error-checking is omitted for clarity. 

    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil; 
    [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL]; 

    if ([isDirectory boolValue]) { 
        NSString *localizedName = nil; 
        [url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL]; 

        NSNumber *isPackage = nil; 
        [url getResourceValue:&isPackage forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey error:NULL]; 

        if ([isPackage boolValue]) { 
            NSLog(@"Package at %@", localizedName); 
        } 
        else { 
            NSLog(@"Directory at %@", localizedName); 
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"File at %@", url);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a comment is too big to fit, you should probably be editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use NSOperation as demonstrated in [NSOperationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html). This involves putting the enumeration inside an NSOperation, placing it on the queue, and having the enumeration loop post NSNotifications which the window controller is registered to observe so that the GUI can update a counter and table of filenames (which the suggested events architecture was unlikely to facilitate readilyi) as the enumerator finds the files. Inside the enumeration loop, it checks the isCancelled flag to see if the user clicked a "Stop" button in the GUI and breaks out of the enumeration if yes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need NSTask in this case. Read about the [Event Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html). If you have assembled the parts correctly, you can still respond to user events while running a process like enumeration. Try it.

Comment: Thanks user757395 but I'm sorry that I don't quite follow.  I read through the suggested link but I don't understand if you are suggesting that the long-running process (the loop in my code) _raises_ events.  This would seem to be what's required for my GUI to be able to update itself with progress.

Comment: oops "thanks drewk". What you seem to be suggesting is that my loop be _interrupted_ (i.e. cancelled) by an event such as the user clicking "Cancel" button.  While the above loop runs, my GUI is "frozen" waiting for the loop to finish.  Everything I've read so far discusses keeping the GUI responsive using one of threading or GCD or NSTAsk. Perhaps it's the "assembling the parts correctly" as you mention that I need to understand first. What are the parts, please?

Comment: I just found a sample application by Apple [NSOperationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004184) that shows how to use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue to interrupt NSDirectoryEnumerator enumeration